# figure out the z-index in my page

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have three z-index level in my [page](http://jsfiddle.net/A2gZc/)

- `z-index: 1` for the div in `position: fixed` with the image positioned as background
- `z-index: 2` for the div sliding box in `position: absolute` which falls down if you click over the producto link (click twice in the producto link in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/A2gZc/))
- `z-index: 3` for the the div in `position: relative` with my header and content

I want to keep the space in z-index: 2 with the image in background exactly till the same point where my sliding box falls down if you click over the Producto link but then i want again my content in z-index:3. in order to keep the div in z-index: 1 as a small window with my image inside.

I am struggling to achieve that, i think it's a very stupid think at this stage.

Hope the explanation is clear, otherwise tell me what's unclear

Comment: If I remmber correctly, positioing elements start a fresh z-index context(starting point) and sometimes inorder to spread them up and sequeze some in between, value like 5000 or even 10000 are given.

Answer (score 1):

found out the issue, i was applying twice the background-color in div z-index 3, that's why i didnt see the div in z-indez: 1